# Change hot spot color in HTML on mouse over

Tags: html

How to change hot spot color in HTML on mouse over?

Comment: What is a hot spot color?

Answer (score 2):

if you mean the hover-color , you could do it like this (:hover-pseudo-class):

```
.myelement:hover{
  color:#ff0000;
  background-color:#00ff00;
}
```

(this works also with class- or tag-selectors, but only on `a` in old IE versions)

if anything else is meant by "hot spot color": i've no idea what you're talking about...